# Xamarin.iOS Runtime Error on call to PerformanceSelector() makes app crash

Tags: xamarin, crash, xamarin.ios, runtimeexception

When making this call to PerformSelector...

```
    var tableView = view.GetAncestors().OfType2<UITableView>().First2();
    var indexPath = tableView.IndexPathForCell(view.To<UITableViewCell>());

    tableView.SelectRow(indexPath, true, UITableViewScrollPosition.None);

    tableView
        .PerformSelector(new Selector("delegate"))
        .If(_ => _.RespondsToSelector(new Selector("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")))
        .SafeNav(_ => _.PerformSelector(new Selector("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:"), tableView, indexPath));
```

I get this unknown exception in the ObjCRuntime...

```
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical: Stacktrace:
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr) <0x00057>
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:   at ObjCRuntime.Class.GetClassForObject (intptr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:134
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:   at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (intptr,ObjCRuntime.Runtime/MissingCtorResolution,bool) [0x00022] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:1017
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:   at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (intptr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:1005
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:   at Foundation.NSObject.PerformSelector (ObjCRuntime.Selector,Foundation.NSObject,Foundation.NSObject) [0x0006f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/Foundation/NSObject.g.cs:439
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:    0   MonoTouchClient                     0x00083f11 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 240
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:    1   MonoTouchClient                     0x0008ba15 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 222
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:    2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x2203a077 _sigtramp + 42
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:    3   MonoTouchClient                     0x007c19d8 wrapper_managed_to_native_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 100
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:    4   MonoTouchClient                     0x0074c9e0 ObjCRuntime_Class_GetClassForObject_intptr + 44
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:    5   MonoTouchClient                     0x0074a89c ObjCRuntime_Runtime_GetNSObject_intptr_ObjCRuntime_Runtime_MissingCtorResolution_bool + 116
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:    6   MonoTouchClient                     0x0074a81c ObjCRuntime_Runtime_GetNSObject_intptr + 36
Warning (13816) / MonoTouchClient: critical:    7   MonoTouchClient                     0x00770bd0 Foundation_NSObject_PerformSelector_ObjCRuntime_Selector_Foundation_NSObject_Foundation_NSObject + 440
```

*Notably, this is only reproducible on an iPad 2 w/ iOS 9.3.5 and not an iPad Pro w/ iOS 10.1.1*

Nothing I change seems to make a difference. Has anyone encountered this before or have any debugging tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Xamarin's `PerformSelector` overload that takes two arguments is expecting a return value from the selector.
i.e.

On `Xamarin.iOS.Foundation.NSObject`:

```
public virtual NSObject PerformSelector(Selector aSelector, NSObject object1, NSObject object2);
```

It then sends this to a native method which tries to marshall the return.

In the question code, the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of the table's delegate was returning `void`. Therefore, the native code attempted to marshall nil, which was causing the error.

The solution was to create my own overload for `PerformSelector(Selector aSelector, NSObject object1, NSObject object2)` and call the native method myself:

### Solution

First, define the native method...

```
public static class MonoTouchNative
{
    [DllImport("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib")]
    public static extern void objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1, IntPtr arg2, IntPtr arg3);
}
```

And then, call it from an new extension method named `PerformVoidSelector`...

```
public static void PerformVoidSelector(this NSObject nsObject, Selector aSelector, NSObject object1, NSObject object2)
{
    MonoTouchNative.objc_msgSend(
        nsObject.Handle,
        Selector.GetHandle("performSelector:withObject:withObject:"),
        aSelector.Handle,
        (object1 != null) ? object1.Handle : IntPtr.Zero,
        (object2 != null) ? object2.Handle : IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Lastly, I called my new extension method from the app code...

```
tableView
    .PerformSelector(new Selector("delegate"))
    .If(_ => _.RespondsToSelector(new                  Selector("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")))
    .SafeDo(_ => _.PerformVoidSelector(new Selector("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:"), tableView, indexPath));
```